# Swift CoreData NSPredicate

Tags: swift, core-data

I have two entities: Game and Player.
A game can have multiple players.

Now I want to fetch all players of a certain game:

```
    let request = NSFetchRequest()
    request.entity = GameDescription

    let pred = NSPredicate(format: "(entity = %@)","Entity")
    request.predicate = pred
```

Can I give a entity parameter to the NSPredicate to give back all the players of for example "Game1" ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use predicate to to fetch a specific game using a attribute value of game that is unique for each game (gameIdentifier)

```
let pred = NSPredicate(format: "(SELF.gameIdentifier == %@)","Game1")
```

also set your request to includesSubentities to Yes.